# What does g'\"" mean?

Tags: vimscript

Also, how can I go about finding out what a sequence means? Lets say I see a command

```
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```

and I want to find  out what some sequences mean? Google does not allow searching for symbols, it just ignores them, so I rarely find anything.

Comment: use vim's `:help`, not google.  `:help g`, `:help g'`, `:help '"`

Comment: Also, symbolhound.com is an imperfect solution for searching the internet for specific symbols/regexes, if you want alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif`
```

This is `if else` statement which can be written as follows:

```
if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") 
  exe "normal! g'\"" 
endif`
```

The meaning of `au BufReadPost` can be found here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufReadPost

`g'\"` means go to the mark `"`, but don't change the jumplist when                        jumping within the current buffer as pointed out here: https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#mark-motions

Here the mark `"` indicates: *jump to position where last exited current buffer*

If you ran `g'"` in normal mode in VIM it would work fine, but you are running a normal mode command in `Ex`mode, which is why you need to use the `\` to escape the `"`.

Comment: Good explanation of the equivalence to `if else` but you do realise you didn't actually answer the question *specifically* asked in the title, yes? The `What does g'\“” mean?` one. It would probably be a more complete answer if you covered that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @paxdiablo. I modified the answer before. I was actually explaining the post, rather than the title of OP..